# Post made up of blocks (text, image, video)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a image site with a similar form for adding posts as on Imgur. A post should be made up of *unlimited* number of blocks of various types (text, image, video) that create finished blog post.

User chooses with which block he wants to start (maybe upload an image) and then adds another block by clicking a button.

I can't figure out a sensible model for blocks that would make up a single post.

This is my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
text = models.TextField() #just a placeholder until blocks work
created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
isWaiting = models.BooleanField(default=True)
isLocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
tags = TaggableManager(help_text="")
```

I don't know if I should define separate models for textblock, imageblock and videoblock (all with ForeignKey to Post model) or if there's a better solution.

I thought of a universal model that would store a TextField (for text written by the user) and a FileField (for image and video upload) used for every block type but one of the Fields in every record would always be empty (user can only write text or upload a file per block) and it seems like a "waste of space".

I appreciate any ideas for solving this problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right. You will need to have several models for Text post, Image, File or anything else you need. All of them should have FK to a Post and an Order field. Just like here for example: https://www.mitsubishi-motors.com.au/blog/8-essentials-prepare-awesome-couples-road-trip/ Each blog post is a combination of block of different types.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance! I see it works beautifully on Mistsubishi's site.  One more question - as far as I know I should use Formsets in Django for creating and processing of the finished post and (JS + AJAX) for adding additional blocks. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across a similar problem I chose a universal content block design with many fields (some are empty depending on a block type, ex. *media* is empty when adding text block). It was easier for me to implement and later add necessary JS for dynamically adding more PostBlocks to Post.

Relevant models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = TaggableManager(help_text="")

class PostBlock(models.Model):
    POST_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('TXT', 'Text'),
        ('IMG', 'Image'),
        ('VID', 'Video'),
    )
    postid = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=True)
    media = models.FileField(upload_to=content_path, blank=True, validators=[
                             validate_file_extension])
    contenttype = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=POST_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='IMG',
    )
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

One *Post* can have as many *PostBlocks* as you need.